# Is there a way to pass binding context to 'if' binding in knockout?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

Here is a little jsfiddle example of what I have to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/SHjXg/3/

Since knockout won't let me bind 'with' and 'if' bindings to a single element I have currently used 2 nested divs instead of one to accomplish this.

```
<div class="item" data-bind="with:items.item1">
    <div data-bind="if:ready()">
        <!-- content here is different for each item and depends on item 
             properties which are not available before ready() is set to true. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I somehow pass the binding context along with existing 'if' binding to use only one div per item or should I create a custom binding for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a syntax like:

`<div class="item" data-bind="template: { data: items.item1, 'if': items.item1.ready }">`

There is only a minor difference between this syntax and the current version of `with` in that this will not preserve the original elements.

Otherwise, you could choose to use a containerless binding like:

`<!-- ko if: ready -->content<!-- /ko -->`

Comment: I was concidering using a template but the only recurring part of the item is the container div itself and thus I'd like to preserve the original elements as well. I have to take a guess that a context cant be changed along the if binding. Does adding containerless cause less overhead than using a custom binding?

Comment: If you use `template` without a `name`, then it uses the children as the "template".  It takes a copy of the element to reuse, whenever the data changes.  I think that would likely be your easiest option. Adding the containerless `if` binding does not add much additional overhead though.  My comment about preserving original elements was just to clarify the minor difference between `with` and the `template` binding specified this way.

Answer (score 1):

If I undertood you right, you could use [virtual element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) :

```
<div class="item" data-bind="with:items.item1">
    <!-- if : ready() -->       
        <!-- content here is different for each item and depends on item 
             properties which are not available before ready() is set to true. -->
     <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that does get rid of the extra div but would using a virtual element cause more overhead than a custom binding? Say if I happen to have something like a hundred of those items on my page, it's still calling 2 binders..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the incredibly useful knockout comments.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

```
<ul>
    <li>This item always appears</li>
    <!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
        <li>I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```